# Running php script after finishing curl

Tags: php, curl

my php code is executed after a form is submitted. The problem is that the curl request apparently is not yet finished when calling the `var_dump()`. Thus the output is `NULL`. I tried it with a while loop but that takes too much time.

```
$crl2 = curl_init();
$headr2 = array();
$headr2[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr2[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr2[] = 'AuthenticationToken:'. $token;
curl_setopt($crl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr2);
curl_setopt($crl2, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($crl2, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

curl_setopt($crl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rest2 = curl_exec($crl2);
curl_close($crl2);

$character = json_decode($rest2);
while($character==NULL){

}
var_dump($character);
```

How can I call the `var_dump($character)` only when the curl is finished ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$token` and `$url` is not defined (?)

Comment: cURL is not Async be default as far as I am aware, which means the code will not continue executing until the request is complete. Something else must be the issue.

Comment: Make sure that `$rest2` contains proper JSON.

Comment: But sometimes it works. Sometimes I get an output string.

Comment: Then apparently in the other cases your request failed or actually didn't return content. PHP is synchronous by default, this code will execute top to bottom and curl has finished when it comes to the var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check whether the request was successfully executed or not?

```
curl_getinfo($crl2,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: But when I just get the info whether it is successfully executed or not I have the same problem: 
Maybe it says that it is not executed successfully but it still continues in executing the code. 
I have to use a while loop again, that takes too long.

Comment: Post the output of print_r($rest2);

Comment: You don't **have** to use a loop. You could easily replace it with an `if / else` clause.

Comment: But when I am using an `If / else`, I am going to get the same issue. The if else is just executed once. If the curl is not ready at the moment the `If / else` is called it simply will not be executed.

Comment: Again, code execution will not continue past `curl_exec()` until it's completed.

Comment: It will. If I am doing the while, it takes some time but then it is executed correctly.